# smoothDivScroll on multiple divs on same page

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Working with the great plugin for smooth-scrolling a div horizontally.
using: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com

I have two sections on one page that i want to be able to target with this feature. Right now when i add another id / instance to the jquery function call it will only apply it to the first one on the page

```
$("div#jobs,div#companies").smoothDivScroll({
    hotSpotScrolling: false,
    touchScrolling: true,
    mousewheelScrolling: false
});
```

Any idea how to get this to apply to X number of scrollable regions on 1 page...

**Adding:**
Here is the markup for the divs:

```
        <div id="jobs" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:143px;left:15px;width:305px;height:135px;overflow:auto;">
            <img src="images/jobs-row.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="companies" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;top:336px;left:15px;width:305px;height:132px;overflow:auto;">
            <img src="images/companies-horizontal.png" />
        </div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: They are in this case. I have two divs with unique ids for each... this way i could target each of them as i needed separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"IDs must be unique on context page" Yes it is. So use class instead:

```
<div id="jobs"></div>
<div id="jobs"></div>
```

Became:

```
<div class="jobs"></div>
<div class="jobs"></div>


$("div.jobs,div.companies").smoothDivScroll({
    hotSpotScrolling: false,
    touchScrolling: true,
    mousewheelScrolling: false
});
```

Comment: I thought of this method as well before posting and created a reusable targetable class that i could put on whatever i wanted to but the same result happens, it only applies the logic to the first instance on the page...

Comment: You mean plugin apply to only div#jobs? Is it what you call first instance?

Comment: I added the markup that i am using for the two divs that have different ids to maybe help what is going on here. I dont get what is correct in the fiddle example vs what i am doing. I feel that i am doing the same thing but i clearly see it working fine in your fiddle..